# ddply not returning values from function split by variable

Tags: r, plyr

I'm using the ddply function (plyr) to calculate something separately by participant id (*pid*). However, for some reason it's not returning separate values by *pid*, but rather the same value across all *pid*.

Sample data:

```
sdt<-c("Hit","Hit","Miss","Miss","False Alarm","Correct Reject","Correct Reject","Correct Reject",
   "Hit","Hit","Hit","Miss","False Alarm","False Alarm","False ALarm","Correct Reject")

pid<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

adhd_p<-data.frame(sdt,pid)
```

Function:

```
ddply(adhd_p, "pid", summarise,
  hitrate=(count(adhd_p$sdt=="Hit")[[2,2]])/((count(adhd_perf$sdt=="Hit")[[2,2]])+(count(adhd_p$sdt=="Miss")[[2,2]])),
  falsealarmrate=(count(adhd_p$sdt=="False Alarm")[[2,2]])/((count(adhd_p$sdt=="False Alarm")[[2,2]])+(count(adhd_p$sdt=="Correct Reject")[[2,2]])))
```

If it helps to understand what I'm calculating... Participants can either "Hit" (respond affirmatively to target), "Miss" (do not respond to target), "Correct Reject" (do not respond to distractor), or "False Alarm" (respond affirmatively to distractor). Thus, "hitrate" is number of hits/hits+misses, and "falsealarmrate" is number of false alarms/false alarms+correct reject.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Edit: Above problem solved very quickly by editing code to

```
 ddply(adhd_p, "pid", summarise,
  hitrate=(count(sdt=="Hit")[[2,2]])/((count(sdt=="Hit")[[2,2]])+(count(sdt=="Miss")[[2,2]])),
  falsealarmrate=(count(sdt=="False Alarm")[[2,2]])/((count(sdt=="False Alarm")[[2,2]])+(count(adhd_p$sdt=="Correct Reject")[[2,2]])))
```

I realize now that I need to split over two variables rather than just one. However adding a time variable:

```
time<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

And merging it in with the others

```
adhd_p<-data.frame(sdt,pid,time)
```

Makes the new script produce a "subscript out of bounds" error.

```
ddply(adhd_p, .(pid,time), summarise,
  hitrate=(count(sdt=="Hit")[[2,2]])/((count(sdt=="Hit")[[2,2]])+(count(sdt=="Miss")[[2,2]])),
  falsealarmrate=(count(sdt=="False Alarm")[[2,2]])/((count(sdt=="False Alarm")[[2,2]])+(count(sdt=="Correct Reject")[[2,2]])))
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to be doing:

```
ddply(adhd_p, "pid", summarise,
  hitrate=(count(sdt=="Hit")[[2,2]])/((count(sdt=="Hit")[[2,2]])+(count(sdt=="Miss")[[2,2]])),
  falsealarmrate=(count(sdt=="False Alarm")[[2,2]])/((count(sdt=="False Alarm")[[2,2]])+(count(sdt=="Correct Reject")[[2,2]])))
```

Why you need to be doing it:

When you call `ddply`, the function works within the `.data` (`adhd_p` in your case) as the local namespace. This is similar to calling `attach(adhd_p)`; calling the name of a column without referencing the dataframe explicitly still calls the correct column.

When you supply the `summarise` argument, the function splits up vectors in the local namespace based on the the id columns supplied (in this case, `pid`). So, if you reference columns without referencing the dataframe explicitly as above, calculations will be done with the portion of the `sdt` column corresponding to each `pid`. However, if you reference the column and dataframe explictly (`adhd_p$sdt` in your case), it just pulls in the entire vector from the global namespace and doesn't split it appropriately.

Edit: the code below is both less messy and won't raise an error if one of the values is missing:

```
ddply(adhd_p, .(pid, time), summarise,
      hitrate=(sum(sdt=="Hit"))/(sum(sdt=="Hit"))+(sum(sdt=="Miss")),
      falsealarmrate=(sum(sdt=="False Alarm"))/(sum(sdt=="False Alarm"))+(sum(sdt=="Correct Reject")))
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for the explanation! It helps to have it spelled out like that.

Comment: As a follow-up question, how would I repeat the procedure above but split by a second variable, (say if there were a 'time' variable across which each participant varied)? I tried changing "pid" to c("pid","time"), but it returns the error: "Error: subscript out of bounds"

Comment: The `.variables` argument can accept a vector, so you can use `ddply(adhd_p, c("pid", "time"), ...)`. This will generate every combination found in the data frame (pid 1 at time 1, pid 1 at time 2, pid 2 at time 1, etc).

Comment: Alternate syntax: `ddply(adhd_p, .(pid, time), ...)`

Comment: I get that error--subscript out of bounds. If you get the time, try adding time<-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4) to the previous data frame: adhd_p<-data.frame(sdt,pid,time).

Comment: Edited post above for more clarity

Comment: The problem is your use of `count()`: if the value you search for doesn't appear, there will be no `True` row and getting the value at `[[2,2]]` won't work. Instead, replace `count(x==y)[[2,2]]` with `sum(x==y)`. Note that in this dataset, you will get a lot of NaNs due to division by 0, you'll have to decide how to handle these cases. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: At this point, if you're having additional problems, you should really post a new question rather than bringing them here. We've moved well beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: Joe, thank you. I'll look to those changes and make a new question if anything else comes up.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't delved into why what you are doing is wrong, but here is an answer that might help:

```
ddply(
  adhd_p, "pid", summarize, 
  hitrate=sum(sdt == "Hit") / sum(sdt %in% c("Hit", "Miss")),
  falsealarmrate=sum(sdt == "False Alarm") / sum(sdt %in% c("False Alarm", "Correct Reject"))
)
```

Produces:

```
  pid hitrate falsealarmrate
1   1    0.50      0.2500000
2   2    0.75      0.6666667
```

Comment: The key seems to be removing the explicit reference to the dataframe (adhd_p$sdt) is the key to the problem. Thank you.